# LLVM/Clang-Based Symbol Lookup Tool

Tags: c++, c, tags, symbols, lookup

Can libclang or some other LLVM/Clang based tool be used to lookup symbol definitions given either a symbol name or even better a file byte-offset? I want to use this from within Emacs.

Comment: Does it have to be LLVM-based? What about using Emacs [etags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/etags.html)?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at [cc-lookup](https://github.com/nonoob/cc-lookup) and have a try:-)